# swift 4 and Xcode autoLayout and UIImageview as Button

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, autolayout, swift4

I am working on auto layout and making those UIIMages as Button.
I would like to make those button to be clicked and switch the images
as well as showing some words in the label.

In this case what should I do?

In addition, as it is shown, the auto layout ratio is different only from the iPhone SE. In. this case What should I consider?

Many thanks,[image: storyboard screenshot]

Comment: Start here to understand auto-layout: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ --- and start here to learn about acting on a button tap and setting properties: https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to learn is **[auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/).** Start with basic Always go with Apple's doc first

This one I likes he is good and you will also find how to use buttons as image view, using card game example, check other tutorials also very helpfull.
[Stanford university autolayout by Michel Deiman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kl2bDYiSgoc&t=1s)

As far, your question just gives your label Horizontal in the container constraints(open storyboard in the right bottom third from last (allin) click on it popUp will open), and 20 bottom to the buttons and it will be in the centre. Every elements need x,y height and width so it knows exactly where to place, so you also need to give constraints to the buttons, Learn [stackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html) to understand how to place your button without giving many constraints to each button and stack view will handle it for you, try hide and show to one of the button and magically stack view will adjust all adjustment. I suggest before staring Do read apple's doc first.

And Your question is too broad to answer, so read and try adding different constraints based on your need and ask a specific question(after trying by yourself) like why this label getting cut what constraints should i add so people know exactly what you want to achieve, people are always ready to help, just ask the right question.

## happyCoding